# Accesing a nested table column

Tags: postgresql, ddl

If I have for example this table:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 OF TYPE type1
(
    PRIMARY KEY (col1)
);
```

And a second table that containts the nested table:

```
CREATE TABLE table2
(
    Col2 table1
);
```

How do I access col1 of nested table col2?

Answer (score 2):

That's not a "nested table" (at least not in the sense as e.g. Oracle uses that term). The column still only contains a "single value" (which is a record though), not multiple rows.

The second table contains a single column with the *type* `table1` which is a composite type (a.k.a. "record").

To access the fields of the composite type, you need to [enclose the column name in parentheses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION):

```
select *
from table2
where (col2).id = 42;
```

Assuming that the *type* `type1` has a field named `id`